# Why wont the product description attribute, when set to TextArea, convert line breaks to <br>

Tags: product-attribute, product-description

Magento v2.4.2

My product description attribute was set to TextArea, and its worked fine for the last year. New lines where rendered as 
 in HTML on the product page. I decided to change it to TextEditor so I can use HTML. I didnt realize when I did that, all my non HTML descriptions would lose all their formatting and new lines or line breaks would no longer render as 
 and my descriptions would look like one giant run on paragraph.

So I changed the attribute back to TextArea thinking it would revert back. It didnt. There is still new line or line breaks in all the product descriptions, so the data is still here. Its just not rendering like it used to.

I have cleared the cache, redeployed etc etc...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to fix it and am going to post it here in case others run in to the same issue.

I compared the catalog_eav_attribute table to my dev version, and the is_html_allowed_on_front column for the product description attribute was set to 1 on production, but 0 on dev. I changed it to 0, and now the product descriptions are formatted correctly on the storefront.

Apparently when you change the Input type from Text Area to Text Editor it changes is_html_allowed_on_front to 1. When you change from Text Editor back to Text Area, it does not change it back to 0.